# Generic mismatch

Tags: java, generics

I am currently getting a generic error and i am unsure how to fix it.

My class has the attributes:

```
LinkedList<ListElement<UidDate>> followers;
LinkedList<ListElement<UidDate>> following;
```

when i try to call the method getHead();

```
ListElement<UidDate> ptr = following.getHead();
```

i get the error:

```
ListElement<ListElement<UidDate>> cannot be converted to ListElement<UidDate>
```

my getHead() method in my linked list class is as follows:

```
public ListElement<E> getHead() {
   return this.head;
}
```

I've not really looked at generics much, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `ListElement<E>` is using the `E` type parameter from `LinkedList<E>`.

Change your `ListElement<E>` return type to E:

```
public E getHead() {
    return head;
}
```